# KITTI dataset: ground truth labels (bird's eye view) match after an image generation?

Tags: ros, point-clouds, kitti

I would like to take the binary **point cloud data** from the **KITTI dataset** and use a suitable node in ROS to generate .png images from point cloud data from a **bird's eye view (bev)**. For this I choose the way:

.bin file -> rosbag file -> .png image

**or alternatively**

.bin file -> sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 -> .png image

The most important question for me would be whether the messages are always sent **synchronously** to the node that handles the conversion when a rosbag file is played back. So the **ground truth** and the **respective image** must **always match**. I am afraid that this is not always guaranteed.

Many thanks for your help